# Is it possible to activate a windows application window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, web

I am trying to build a web page that will contain a list of windows from another Windows application (Trade Ideas).  Is it possible for me to use links in this web page to activate the Trade Ideas windows?  In other words I would use Javascript to activate the corresponding Trade Ideas window when it's name is chosen from the list.

Comment: Not without some sort of native (ActiveX or whatever it's called now) plugin, and only Internet Explorer would support that. Think about what the world would be like if random web pages could do things to other applications running on your machine ...

Comment: Yes, you can use links to activate desktop apps. Read more on ClickOnce or Java Web Start, both technologies should do the job for you.

Comment: Do these need to be ClickOnce applications? i.e. can I only activate ClickOnce apps?  Trade Ideas is a native windows application.

Comment: yes, you need to download a unique mime type file, then when the browser asks how to handle the file, choose your application and remember the association. Now, you can simply trigger a download of that type to launch the application. eg: `download("commandName", "temp.myx", "x-application/opener")` using https://github.com/rndme/download should start the "interview process"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that.

Comment: @rob: i added more detail, but it's basically just how you can choose an app to open a download, just like you do for a zip or word doc, only it's for a file type that doesn't exist, so that the OS will ask you what app to use. when you download the file again (which js can trigger unattended), the app opens.  you have a proper logical downloads setup in the browser; you need to NOT do things like "always ask" or "save to a custom location" in download settings, but it CAN work in FF or Chrome for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution to this problem.  I created a batch file that uses the nircmd utility.  The batch file reads:

```
nircmd.exe win activate title "windowtitle"
```

I downloaded and installed a program called:

```
LocalExplorer
```

After that, I can use a link in my web page:

```
<a href = "localexplorer:C:\bat.bat">Window Name</a>
```

And it will run the batch file which will activate the window.